# Python - Importing a global/site-packages module rather than the file of the same name in the local directory

Tags: python, django, import, python-module

I'm using python and virtualenv/pip. I have a module installed via pip called `test_utils` (it's django-test-utils). Inside one of my django apps, I want to import that module. However I also have another file `test_utils.py` in the same directory. If I go `import test_utils`, then it will import this local file.

Is it possible to make python use a non-local / non-relative / global import? I suppose I can just rename my `test_utils.py`, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my `test_utils` was in a django project, I was able to go `from ..test_utils import ...` to import the global one.

Answer (score 5):

You can switch the search order by changing sys.path:

```
del sys.path[0]
sys.path.append('')
```

This puts the current directory after the system search path, so local files won't shadow standard modules.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to force python to import the global one with
`from __future__ import absolute_import`
at the beginning of the file (this is the default in python 3.0)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was even more elaborate:

## importing a `global/site-packages` module ***from a file*** with the same name

Working on [aero the pm recycler](https://github.com/Aeronautics/aero) I wanted access to the pip api, in particular `pip.commands.search.SearchCommand` from my adapter class Pip in source file pip.py.

In this case trying to modify `sys.path` is useless, I even went as far as wiping `sys.path` completely and adding the folder `.../site-packages/pip...egg/` as the only item in `sys.path` and no luck.

I would still get:

```
print pip.__package__
# 'aero.adapters'
```

I found two options that did eventually work for me, they should work equally well for you:

### using `__builtin__.__import__()` the built-in function

```
global_pip = __import__('pip.commands.search', {}, {}, ['SearchCommand'], -1)
SearchCommand = global_pip.SearchCommand
```

Reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) though, suggests using the following method instead.

### using `importlib.import_module()` the `__import__` conv wrapper.

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) explains that `import_module()` is a minor subset of functionality from Python 3.1 to help ease transitioning from 2.7 to 3.1

```
from importlib import import_module
SearchCommand = import_module('pip.commands.search').SearchCommand
```

Both options get the job done while `import_module()` definitely feels more Pythonic if you ask me, would you agree?

nJoy!

Answer (score 0):

You could reset your `sys.path`:

```
import sys
first = sys.path[0]
sys.path = sys.path[1:]
import test_utils
sys.path = first + sys.path
```

The first entry of `sys.path` is "always" (as in "per default": See [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path)) the current directory, so if you remove it you will do a global import.

Answer (score 0):

Though, in first place, I would always consider keeping the name of local file not matching with any global module name, an easy workaround, without modifying 'sys.path' can be to include global module in some other file and then import this global module from that file.

Remember, this file must be in some other folder then in the folder where file with name matching with global module is.

For example. 
*./project/root/workarounds/global_imports.py*

```
import test_utils as tutil
```

and then in 
*./project/root/mycode/test_utils.py*

```
from project.root.workarounds.global_imports import tutil
# tutil is global test_utils

# you can also do 
from project.root.workarounds.global_imports import test_utils
```