# How to explicitly import a global python package instead of from local file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have exactly opposite issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11489330/2215679).

In my case I have:

logging.py

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(..)
```

I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getLogger'
```

This happens only on project with python 2.7 run under Pyramid framework.

When I run it in another project, python 3.6 without any framework it works perfect.

PS. there is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299199/python-importing-a-global-site-packages-module-rather-than-the-file-of-the-sam), but it is different case, in my case it is global package that is not present in any `sys.path` folder. So none of solutions from that question worked for me.
Please don't mark this issue as duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution, just putting:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

on top of the file will resolve the issue.

source: [https://docs.python.org/2/library/**future**.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html)

As you may see, in python 3>= absolute import is by default

Answer (score 1):

> It is better to rename your local file to be different with builtin module name.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I want to avoid it, as it will require to update all my other services that used the same code.